# Efficiently remove points with same slope

Tags: c#, .net, performance, algorithm, geometry

In one of mine applications  I am dealing with graphics objects. I am using open source [GPC library](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/)   to clip/merge two shapes. To improve accuracy I am sampling (adding multiple points between two edges) existing shapes. But before displaying back the merged shape I need to remove all the points between two edges.

But I am not able to find an efficient algorithm that will remove all points between two edges which has same slope with minimum CPU utilization. Currently all points are of type

```
PointF
```

I am calculating slope using following function

```
  private float Slope(PointF point1, PointF point2)
  {
     return (point2.Y - point1.Y) / (point2.X - point1.X);
  }
```

Any pointer on this will be a great help.

Comment: A more specific title would be helpful.

Comment: Could you draw some ASCII art to show what you mean? They say a picture paints a thousand words, and it would really help anyone to understand your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I found the solution for my question. Instead of using Sampling method provided by SDK, I created my own sampling method which insert a point between two points at a fixed distance. This reduces the number of point that I need to process and in turn reducing processor usage.

Answer (score 1):

What algorithm are you currently using? I can think only of going through all point and for each 3 to check wherher middle point is on vector (or close to) defined by 2 other points.
Do you need math for that operation?

Comment: Currently I am iterating through all points are removing the middle one if its slope is similar to the first and last point's slope. But this operation is taking much more time.

I am looking for optimized math for this operation

Comment: @ Ravi: I calculating slope using following function

      private float Slope(PointF point1, PointF point2)
      {
         return (point2.Y - point1.Y) / (point2.X - point1.X);
      }

Comment: How much points do you have? I dont think, that math is bottle neck here. How do you iterate through points? How are they sorted? Are they in array or list? Removing point from array could take some time! Better use list!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you have three points A = (a,b), C = (c,d), and E = (e,f), and are wondering if the segment AE goes through C and thus you can replace the pair of segments AC and CE with the single segment AE?

slope AC = (d-b)/(c-a) = slope CE = (f-d)/(e-c)

multiply through by the denominators, you get
(d-b)(e-c) = (f-d)(c-a)

that's just four subtracts, two multiplies, and a compare.  You'll need to do the comparison with some error tolerance due to the use of floating point.